# How can we represent set $S= \{z:|z|>|z-1|\}$ graphically.

Tags: geometry, graphing-functions, plane-curves

Here I have plotted graph of $|z|$ and $|z-1|$ but I am not getting the required condition. I have to plot this using divs in a plane for which general set is $\{z:|z-z_0|<r\}$ where $r$ is radius centered at $z_0$.

Comment: $S$ is the set of points closer to $1$ than to $0$. The set of points equidistant from $0$ and $1$ is the vertical line halfway between $0$ and $1$. Points to the left of that line are closer to $0$, points to the right are closer to $1$.

Comment: It is $\{z: \Re z >1/2\}$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 2):

Your condition reads: the distance from $z$ to the origin is greater than the distance to the real number $1$. If you draw the bisector of the segment joining $0$ and $1$, your region is the right half-plane.

Answer (score -1):

$|z| > |z-1|$ basically translates to, "Find the points $z$ such that the distance from $z$ to the origin is greater than the distance between $z$ & $1$". This is what the graph looks like, please pretend the $y$-axis is the complex axis. [image]